# Translation missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Hi I have a validation in my app as follows:

```
class account

  validate  :check_no_imports

  def check_no_imports
    if imports.any?
      errors.add(:base, :check_no_imports)
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my en.yml I have:

```
activerecord:
    errors:
      account:
        check_no_imports: 'error message'
```

However when I run this I get:

`translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.account.attributes.base.check_no_imports`

I'm not sure why this would be the case, a similar format is working for other validations, but not this one?

Comment: Did you restart your rails server in-between adding the new translation key and using it?

Comment: It's in a spec that translation key is being called. So essentially yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few keys, `models`, `attributes`, `base`, try with:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      account:
        attributes:
          base:
            check_no_imports: error message
```

Comment: But why does it work with other errors on base, but not this one?

Comment: Maybe they're specified that way, not as in the structure you see now. Note you can specify which key to use when adding new errors and its yaml value.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today. If you only use English, you can fix is just by passing a string message instead of a symbol.

```
errors.add(:base, "check no imports")
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the string syntax is throwing the "can't have more than one repeating rule" again under Rails 7.0.4 and Ruby 3.1.2.